# React Native Runs Without Errors Doesn't Start on Device?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

Running through [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/react-native-tutorial-part-1-hello-react) tutorial on Mac OSX, I have android studio installed and built a Nexus 5 emulator (API 27, Android 8.1.0). When running the `react-native run-android` command, there are no errors if the emulator is running through android studio, but the app does not begin running on the emulator.

(Note, I got this working last week on a loaner from work computer while my assigned laptop was being repaired, same OS, both macbook pro 15; the app would auto-start on the emulator)

If I run the command without the emulator on, I get this output:

```
JS server not recognized, continuing with build...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

If I run the command with the emulator on, I get this output:

```
JS server not recognized, continuing with build...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Task :app:installDebug 
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_27(AVD) - 8.1.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
Starting the app (adb shell am start -n  com.reactcalculator/com.reactcalculator.MainActivity...
```

The emulator never changes.

---

## Solution

The app was on the device; it just didn't start immediately. I was able to find it by checking the apps list thoroughly. It seems that in some environments (like my loaner described above), the app with start on its own, and in other environments, it needs to be manually started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The app is present, it just isn't starting automatically.

The app was on the device; it just didn't start immediately. I was able to find it by checking the apps list thoroughly. It seems that in some environments (like my loaner described above), the app with start on its own, and in other environments, it needs to be manually started.